# Focusable Panel in WPF

Tags: wpf, focus, panel, keydown

I need to make a Panel focusable in WPF, so that it captures keyboard events just as any other focusable control:

- The user clicks inside the Panel to give it focus
- any `KeyDown` or `KeyUp` event is raised at panel level
- if another focusable element outside the panel is clicked, the panel loses focus

I experimented `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"` on the Panel and `myPanel.Focus()` returns `true` but the Panel KeyUp event handler still isn't called.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more investigation, the Panel has the keyboard focus and keeps it until an arrow key or TAB is pressed (which starts the focus cycling).

I just added a handler for the `KeyDown` event with `e.Handled = true;' and now everything works correctly.

To sum it up, to have a focusable Panel:

- add `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"` to the Panel
- prevent from loosing focus on arrows and Tab key with:

> ```
> myPanel.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(
>     delegate(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (e.Key == Key.Left ||
>             e.Key == Key.Up ||
>             e.Key == Key.Right ||
>             e.Key == Key.Down ||
>             e.Key == Key.Tab)
>             e.Handled = true;
>     }
> );
> ```

Finally give it the focus with `myPanel.Focus();`.

Answer (score 1):

If your panel does not contain any child elements, even using `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"` will not fire the GotFocus event. Panel are not designed to take keyboard input or focus. Instead, most of the times (like if the child element is a Button control)  `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"` will even eat up the KeyUp/KeyDown events. The event will not be fired for neither your control nor your panel.

Comment: That's what I understood, but the question remains: What do I need to make a Panel focusable? I wish to extend it (maybe by deriving it) to give it that feature.

Comment: Mart, You might need to derive a panel from IInputElement? Just a guess